# how to save the result of moving a row in a datagridview in the database

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagridview

I have code to move rows in datagridview using mouse drag and drop, but after closing the program or updating the table everything resets. how to make data placement saved in the database?

code that uses mouse events to drag rows around while diplaying one Cell value into a Label.

It inserts the row after you have run it

```
int dragRow = -1;
Label dragLabel = null;

private void dataGridView1_CellMouseDown(object sender,DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex<0 || e.RowIndex < 0) return;
    dragRow = e.RowIndex;
    if (dragLabel == null) dragLabel = new Label();
    dragLabel.Text = dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
    dragLabel.Parent = dataGridView1;
    dragLabel.Location = e.Location;
}

private void dataGridView1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && dragLabel != null)
    {
        dragLabel.Location = e.Location;
        dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
    }
}


private void dataGridView1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var hit = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X,e.Y);
    int dropRow = -1;
    if (hit.Type != DataGridViewHitTestType.None)
    {
        dropRow =   hit.RowIndex;
        if (dragRow >= 0 )
        {
            int tgtRow = dropRow + (dragRow > dropRow ? 1 : 0);
           if (tgtRow != dragRow)
{
    DataRow dtRow = DT.Rows[dragRow];
    DataRow newRow = DT.NewRow();
    newRow.ItemArray = DT.Rows[dragRow].ItemArray;


    DT.Rows.Remove(dtRow);
    DT.Rows.InsertAt(newRow, tgtRow);
    dataGridView1.Refresh();
    dataGridView1.Rows[tgtRow].Selected = true;
}
        }
    }
    else  { dataGridView2.Rows[dragRow].Selected = true;}



    if (dragLabel != null)
    {
        dragLabel.Dispose();
        dragLabel = null;
    }
}
```

code for displaying data in a table:

```
command = new SqlCommand("select * from ustroystva", connection);
adapter.SelectCommand = command;
table.clear();
adapter.Fill(table);
dataGridViewl.DataSource = table;
dt = table;
adapter.Update (dt);
```

Comment: Add a field to the table that stores the order. Change that field in all involved rows when dropping a row and save that to the db. Order the grid by that column. Your MouseUp code is broken. Is something relevant missing there?

Comment: i fixed MouseUp

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion to "add a field to the table that stores the order" is a good one, but not just 'any' field will do. Suppose the database holds just three items. If we query for Apple | Orange and assign them '1' and '2' for sort order and then query for Orange | Banana and assign *them* '1' and '2' what have we gained? So what has worked for me is to have a time-based `Priority` field for the sort order.

```
[Table("records"), DebuggerDisplay("{Name}")]
class Record
{
    [PrimaryKey, Browsable(false)]
    public string Guid { get; set; } = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    public DateTime Created { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    [Browsable(false)]
    public DateTime Priority { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    [ReadOnly(true)]
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

[image: initial]

---

For the sake of simplicity, suppose we're using `sqlite-net-pcl` instead of `System.Data.SQLite` so that `DataGridView.DataSource` can use a straightforward list binding. *(This has no bearing on the actual answer, it just makes it easier to show the code.)*

```
BindingList<Record> Recordset { get; } = new BindingList<Record>();
```

The [Requery] button click handler is:

```
    buttonRequery.Click += async (sender, e) =>
    {
        Recordset.Clear();
        using (var cnx = new SQLiteConnection(SQLitePath))
        {
            foreach (var item in cnx.Query<Record>("SELECT * FROM records ORDER BY Priority"))
            {
                Recordset.Add(item);
            }
        }
    };
```

[image: after drag drop]

In response, sort the priorities in order and apply them to the items in the new order they exist now before updating the database record.

```
dataGridView.MouseUp += (sender, e) =>
{
    var hit = dataGridView.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
    int dropRow = -1;
    if (hit.Type != DataGridViewHitTestType.None)
    {
        dropRow = hit.RowIndex;
        if (dragRow >= 0)
        {
            int tgtRow = dropRow + (dragRow > dropRow ? 1 : 0);
            if (tgtRow != dragRow)
            {
                var record = Recordset[dragRow];
                Recordset.Remove(record);
                Recordset.Insert(tgtRow, record);
                dataGridView.Refresh();
                dataGridView.Rows[tgtRow].Selected = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if (dragLabel != null)
    {
        dragLabel.Dispose();
        dragLabel = null;

        // Apply the sorted priorities to the items as they now stand in the list.
        var priorities = Recordset.Select(_ => _.Priority).OrderBy(_=>_).ToArray();
        for(int index = 0; index < priorities.Length; index++)
        {
            Recordset[index].Priority = priorities[index];
        }
        using (var cnx = new SQLiteConnection(SQLitePath))
        {
            cnx.UpdateAll(Recordset);
        }
    }
    dataGridView.CurrentCell = hit.ColumnIndex == -1 || hit.RowIndex == -1 ?
        null :
        dataGridView[hit.ColumnIndex, hit.RowIndex];
};
```

---

**Example**

Suppose we have ability to do an ephemeral sort by clicking on the column header. As a test sequence, we can (ephemeral) sort by `Created`, then (ephemeral) sort on `Name`, before hitting the [Requery] button to retrieve the database items in the actual post-drag-drop order.

```
dataGridView.CellClick += (sender, e) =>
{
    if(e.RowIndex == -1)
    {
        Record[] sorted;
        if (dataGridView.Columns[nameof(Record.Created)].Index == e.ColumnIndex)
        {
            sorted = Recordset.OrderBy(_ => _.Created).ToArray();
        }
        else if (dataGridView.Columns[nameof(Record.Name)].Index == e.ColumnIndex)
        {
            sorted = Recordset.OrderBy(_ => _.Name).ToArray();
        }
        else return;
        Recordset.Clear();
        foreach (var item in sorted)
        {
            Recordset.Add(item);
        }
    }
};
```

[image: test sequence]

---

It follows that you can insert `Grape` between Apple and Banana by setting its priority to ((Apple.Priority) + (Banana.Priority)) / 2.

You get the idea.

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/order-of-data.git)