# how to change the order of rows in a datagridview bound to a database so that these changes are saved in the database

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView that is bound to a DataTable and a datatable to a db, is there a way to change the order of rows in the DataGridView and reflect the changes in my database? So that when the program is closed and then opened, the entire string permutation is preserved.
I have the algorithm itself for rearranging rows by pressing the up or down buttons, but these changes are not saved after updating the form/closing the program

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to save the result of moving a row in a datagridview in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77563871/5438626) [https://stackoverflow.com/a/77566418/5438626](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77566418/5438626)

Answer (score 0):

You could store an explicit "Order"-column. This would let the user reorder rows in whatever way he wants, and have this persisted.

Or you could store a sequence of columns used for ordering as well as the sort direction. This should let you replay the sorting whenever the data is loaded the next time. You could store this in a separate table, or to a regular file, depending if you view this being part of the data or a program setting.

Comment: I need the user to be able to move the rows himself and this sequence is saved each time